How do I adjust import and export settings for wavefront .obj files in blender 4.1?
I am enjoying learning Blender, but need to import and export Wavefront .obj files. They swap the y and z axis compared to normal coordinate systems, for example if I export something from cloud compare as .obj and .dxf, the .dxf file comes in as I expect but the .obj file has the y axis converted to z, and the z to -y. Apparently this has been noted by others and one must set the forward axis and up axis for .obj file import and export. But I have been able to find where I should do this.
I have read up on this and the manual says :

Properties
Object Properties
Scale
Forward Axis, Up Axis.

Where do I set this? I have checked the preferences in Blender but don't see it there. Must I manually edit a python file outside of blender? If so which one? Would this change be preserved across Blender upgrades?

I've now added an answer with images below.

Thanks John, that is correct. Last night I asked chatgpt4 and it included the text " on the file import dialog box" which was missing from all the other google searches that I did. Staring me in the face all the time, but I did not notice it.

No problem. Please mark my answer as correct (click the tick mark to turn it green). Thanks.


When in the File selector, hit N or click the top-right Settings gear icon to open the side panel where you'll find the Axis settings used when importing.

Use the dropdowns beside the settings to change the axis settings.
